# Roll over for TimedRotatingFileHandler in python is not happening

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, log-rotation

I have a script which runs every day and is using TimedRoatingLogFileHandler of Python.
Below is an excerpt from the code.

```
log = 'test.log'           # Set up Log title
filename = '/var/log/' + log
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when="D", interval=1, backupCount=45)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("Script execution started")
```

I am expecting a new logfile test.log gets created daily and the previous log will be moved to test.log.1 and test.log.2 etc.

Is my assumption correct?
If so, why is it not happening?
I can see yesterday's output in today's log still. Yesterday's log file is not moved to a different file as I was expecting.
I am using Python 2.7 on a SUSE linux machine.
I have checked the other threads but most of them don't contain any answers.
Please let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: This set up is working. It's my bad. There are lot of files in the folder and i was doing "ls -lrt test*log" instead of "ls -lrt test.log*".

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually log something for rollover to occur. Until your program does this, yesterday's output could still be in the current log.

**Update:** `TimedRotatingFileHandler` is for when the script runs over multiple days, while logging over multiple days. If the script completes every day before the end of the day, you are better off using a `FileHandler` with a filename derived from the date.

Comment: Please see the last line. I have included a "logger.info" statement at the end. And as i have said, this is just an excerpt. A lot more is there in the script and hence lot more logger.info or logger.error statements.